# Using FileTransfer API for Phonegap on Android download fails

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap-plugins, file-transfer

I am trying to implement the FileTransfer API for my Phonegap App in Javascript.  When I call it with the code below I get the following error:

```
01-24 00:36:10.495: I/Web Console(14802): Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at file:///android_asset/www/js/phonegap-1.3.0.js:670
```

Code to call download

```
var fileTransfer1 = new FileTransfer();

fileTransfer1.download(
    "http://www.domain.com/images/file.png",
    "/sdcard/file.png",
    function(entry) {
        alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        alert("upload error code" + error.code);
   }
);
```

I have this in my Manifest:

I have this in my config:

I have cordova-2.2.0.jar in my libs folder and phonegap-1.3.0.js is an included javascript.  I did some debugging in phonegap-1.3.0.js and the error is in the call to prompt:

var r = prompt(JSON.stringify(args), "gap:"+JSON.stringify([service, action, callbackId, true]));

It is returing "29 F08 FileTransfer() sJSON error"  this is passed to an eval function which of course fails.  It would seem I am missing something in my setup somewhere.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: For some reason the lines from my manifest and config did not show in the original question.  Here they are.  Manifest: `    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>` and the Config: `    <plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
    <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have cordova-2.2.0.js if you are using cordova-2.2.0.jar.  They need to match. And make sure you have the appropriate one for android.